# How we can show google analytics reports on our website using PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics

I want to display google analytic reports on my website.
Please let me know is there API provided by Google for this.

Comment: Apparently google is a search engine and you can check for things like this. Apparently.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is, you can add an iframe in your site

Comment: from where, we will get that iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Please setup  tracking code for that.....

Please check below given link it's usefull to you...

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

GA API allow only access to GA data. You need create manually (with html and javascript) the reports.